# Как правильно произносить в русском переводе слова, оканчивающиеся на Н?

Tags: переводы

Если вопрос не по адресу, скажите, но, честно говоря, не знаю, где еще его задать.
Интересует перевод слов, оканчивающихся на букву Н. Вот, например, вспомним рекламу чая "Dilmah". Сначала его название произносили как "Дилмах", потом - как "Дилма". Еще на ум приходят имена собственные из фильмов (например, поклонники "Звездных Войн" знают планету Dagobah, которую тоже переводили то как "Дагобах", то как "Дагоба").
Так как же правильно произносить в русском переводе слова, оканчивающиеся на Н?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от конкретного слова и языка, и, конечно, от особенности русской фонетики. В данном случае слова "Дилмах" не совсем соответствует русскому произношению, поэтому мы взяли более удобную для произношения  норму - "Дилма". Надо учитывать еще тот факт, редуцируется ли согласная Н в языке-оригинале, произносится она или нет. Специальных правил нет.

Answer (score 0):

Это НЕ о переводе слов.

Это о произношении имён и названий из иных языков, которые надо произносить так, как указывает НЕ носитель языка, словарь этого языка. Те имена и названия, которые приняты русским словарём, в словарях и нужно смотреть.

Правила произношения в англ. есть, но следовать им без сверки со словарём НЕЛЬЗЯ!

bow (бау) нос корабля, весло, гребец, поклон.

bow (боу) кривая, лук (оружие), смычок.